# Weird texts when I press enter in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

This has just started to happen.
In Windows Termnial, it looks fine, but VS Code is faulty.

[image: Weird text]

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: the terminal does not understand ANSI Escape sequences